# Is there any open source middleware for authentication, which can implement OIDC code flow. In FastAPI

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, fastapi, middleware

Is there any generic validator for access token in FastAPI, which we can use for authentication,

Answer (score -2):

If you want enterprise level features try KeyCloak(https://www.keycloak.org/) it has lots of features that supports your requirment.